# Bridged network with multiple alias in Debian

Tags: debian, alias

I'v been trying to setup a bridged network with multiple IP addresses for a few days but I cannot get it to work. I'v tried multiple different setups found here on stackoverflow.

Here is my latest that seems to be working for alot of other people, but not for me.

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports enp8s0
    address 192.168.0.155
    netmask 255.255.252.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1

auto br0:1
iface br0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.28
    netmask 255.255.252.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

It shows up in ifconfig

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.155  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 *  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether *  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11626  bytes 7924309 (7.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7425  bytes 1320730 (1.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br0:1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.28  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether *  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

However I cannot ping 192.168.0.28 only 192.168.0.155. I have also setup 192.168.0.100 in a VM and that seems to be working fine.

My iptables allows everything right now for testing

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

My host is telling me everything looks fine in my configs, but apparently something is wrong?
Would really be happy for some help since I'v been at this for a few days now.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you ping 192.168.0.28 from the same host or from a remote host?

Comment: On the machine, I can ping both .155 and .28.
From a remote machine, I can only ping .155.
Using tcpdump I can see the .155 ICMP packages (as expected) but nothing regarding the .28.

I have also tried setting up the machine to ONLY use the .28 ip, which works. So both addresses seem to be available to me.

Comment: check ARP tables and requests on the remote machine.